# How much time passed in the real world while Harry was at King's Cross in the final book?

Tags: harry-potter, time

Harry spends a whole chapter of the last book in King's Cross after getting hit by the killing curse from Voldemort (which sounds to be like at least ten minutes or more), however, it doesn't seem like such a long time has a passed in the forest during this period.

But it doesn't seem like it was instantaneous either, based on the description of the scene in the forest after the end of the King's Cross scene.

How long does the dialogue in King's Cross last?

Comment: Depends on how slowly you read it, I suppose...

Comment: Are you saying that King's Cross wasn't real?!

Comment: it wasn't the physical realm as we know it in the Harry Potter world that's for sure

Answer (score 13):

## A brief amount of time

Upon hitting Harry with the Killing Curse, Voldemort was supposedly knocked out at the same time.

> Harry closed his eyes again and considered what he had seen. The Death Eaters had been huddled round Voldemort, who seemed to have fallen to the ground. Something had happened when he had hit Harry with the Killing Curse. Had Voldemort, too, collapsed? It seemed like it. **And both of them had fallen briefly unconscious and both of them had now returned**.

Except for this quote, there is really no exact evidence to show how long Harry (and Voldemort) was knocked out. Though we do see Bellatrix saying this:

> 'My Lord ... *my Lord* ...'
>
> [...]
>
> '*My Lord* ...'
>
> 'That will do,' said Voldemort's voice.

It takes quite a while for Voldemort to respond – could it be because he was still unconscious?